# Vim's cscope connection breaks on every GNU screen reattach

Tags: vim, freebsd, gnu-screen, cscope

I run `vim` with `cscope` in my C development environment. I start `vim` within a GNU `screen` window on a freebsd 6.3 server and establish the cscope db connection with `cs add ...`. At this stage everything works flawlessly.

If I detach the screen session and reattach it, any attempts to use cscope causes cscope to dump core. This is all I have from the core dump since my cscope is not compiled with debug symbols:

```
(gdb)
#0  0x480f45dc in ungetch () from /lib/libncurses.so.6
(gdb)
```

AFAIK there is no need to re-establish the cscope connection on vim when I reattach to screen. That would defeat the purpose of using screen. Anyone knows whats going on and if there is a workaround? If everything fails, I'm going to find time to compile cscope with symbols and figure out whats going on.

If it helps, my cscope DB is generated with:

```
cscope -bkq -P`pwd` -i cscope.files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that this is an issue fixed in cscope 15.7a. Posting an answer here in case someone else has the same issue (it bothered me for a couple of years before I decided to post here).

Comment: Will do, I think I need to wait a few hours for that.

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's crashing in curses even though `vim` is going to invoke `cscope -l` (line mode) I think it is reasonable to guess that `TERM=screen` is related to your problem.  I'd try making a wrapper (for example in `$HOME/bin`, assuming that's before `/usr/local/bin` in your path) to change it:

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! test -t 0
then
    TERM=vt100
fi

exec /usr/local/bin/cscope "$@"
```

Which says "if not running from a tty, fake TERM".  The tty test is to try and avoid breaking interactive use.  You could try `TERM=none` or other values as well.

Comment: I will check this and post here, seems like this could be it!